# Convert a list to Dataframe (Spark Scala)

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have list of object which I want to convert in to data frame

```
 def createDf(list: ListBuffer[TestTO]): DataFrame = {
    val structArrLength = 6
    val cols: Array[StructField] = new Array[StructField](structArrLength)
    cols(0) = StructField("a", StringType, nullable=true)
    cols(2) = StructField("b", StringType, nullable=true)
    cols(3) = StructField("c", StringType, nullable=true)
    cols(4) = StructField("d", DateType, nullable=true)
    cols(5) = StructField("e", BooleanType, nullable=true)

    val schema = StructType(cols)
    val rddMap=sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(list)
    val rows = rddMap.map {  x => Row(Seq(x))}
    val df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
    df.show(false)
}
```

I am getting following error :-
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon is not a valid external type for schema of string

I am new to scala and spark world. If someone can help me to covert list to dataframe in spark/scala , it would be great help.

thank you

Solution :-

```
  def createDf(list: ListBuffer[MaskScheduleTO]): Dataset[Row] = {
    val schema = createMaskSchema
    var data: ListBuffer[Row] = new ListBuffer[Row]
    list.foreach(x => data += Row(x.prop1,x.prop2))
    val rddMap = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(data.toList)
    sparkSession.createDataFrame(rddMap, schema)
  }
  
   private def createMaskSchema = {
    StructType(List(
      StructField("prop1", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("prop2", StringType, nullable = true),
    ))
  }
```

Comment: Than k you @Gael J for correcting title. 

I found the solution of my problem. So, someone can take help if gets stuck with the same problem.  I mentioned the solution in question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :-

```
  def createDf(list: ListBuffer[MaskScheduleTO]): Dataset[Row] = {
    val schema = createMaskSchema
    var data: ListBuffer[Row] = new ListBuffer[Row]
    list.foreach(x => data += Row(x.prop1,x.prop2))
    val rddMap = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(data.toList)
    sparkSession.createDataFrame(rddMap, schema)
  }
  
   private def createMaskSchema = {
    StructType(List(
      StructField("prop1", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("prop2", StringType, nullable = true),
    ))
  }
```